# Access menu bar search via keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, menu-bar

I am used to bring up the menu bar search in any application by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on a US keyboard layout.

However with my new MacBook this only brings up the Help window, since the shortcut for Help is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> which is exactly what <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>) would do (<kbd>?</kbd> is 2nd option on the <kbd>/</kbd> key).

Any idea how to change this behaviour or set this shortcut up manually?

Comment: “Menu Bar Search?”  Do you mean *Spotlight*?  Try `Cmd-Space`

Comment: @Allan no, I mean the search field that appears under "Help" in the menu bar of every application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under System Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts there is a predefined shortcut named "Show Help menu" under App Shortcuts - All Applications. You can set your own keystroke there (I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>).

Comment: This answer does not address the origional question, under the help menu there is a search field that searches menus command within the application.

Comment: It does work :)
Hint: The applications, such as system preferences, need to restart for this to work.